# SQL Server return one row with columns with the minimum and maximum data

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a dataset like this

```
Id  name  StartTime   EndTime
-----------------------------
1   aa    12:00       13:00
2   aa    13:30       15:00
3   aa    15:00       19:00
```

I need a query to return

```
aa,12:00,19:00
```

I want to return record having same name and a column with minimum time and the next one a maximum column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect a simple aggregation and group by should do the trick

```
Select Name
      ,StartTime = min(StartTime)
      ,EndTime   = max(EndTime)
 From  YourTable
 Group By Name
```